# How to print messages on console using console.log

Tags: debugging, console, qml, blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades

I'm printing the messages on console in qmomentics ide.

```
console.log("Simple string message");
```

Then this message is displaying on the device log console.

Now i'm trying to concatenate the other datatypes to the message and printing those messages on the device console. Then that message is not displaying on the console.

```
 property bool finished: false
 console.log("String message concatenated with bool value" +finished);
```

Please tell me how print messages which are concatenated with other datatypes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at this:

```
NavigationPane {
    id: navigationPane
    property bool myProperty: false //OK
    console.log("my string" + myProperty); //NOT HERE!

    function myFunction() { //OK
    }

    onCreationCompleted: {
        console.log("myProperty: " + myProperty); //THIS WORKS
    }
}
```

When I try it like you did IDE already gives me an error. Only definitions are allowed there. You can put it in *onCreationCompleted* or some other function.

Comment: Hi i've given in below function. Then not displaying the message.                                                     onOpened: {
    console.log("Isfinished "+finished);
    if (finished) {
       sheetAssplashPage.close();
    }
 }

Comment: I've tried exactly that, it works for me. Check all your names are correct, and any possible errors you get in a console.

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax is `console.log("String message concatenated with bool value", finished);`

Answer (score 0):

This is likely your answer:

http://devblog.blackberry.com/2012/10/blackberry-10-sdk-console-logging/

You need to install a message handler in order to route the messages to the console.

In your main.cpp file just above the main function, add:

```
void myMessageOutput(QtMsgType type, const char* msg) {
    fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", msg);
    fflush(stdout);
}
```

Then inside the main function, add:

```
qInstallMsgHandler(myMessageOutput);
```